# How do I isolate a singleton in my unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, nunit-2.5

I have a static class in my program.  In the static constructor I create instance of service. The proxy of service is a singleton.

I must write unit tests for this class, and certainly I want isolate this service. 
How can I do it?

In my project we use Rhino.Mocks.

Comment: Edited significantly.  Feel free to roll it back or do additional fixes if I messed anything up :)

Comment: just... don't write singletons. If you want to test your code, step one is going to have to be to actually write testable code. Singletons are not, which is just [one of their many problems](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/).

Comment: I agree with others that Dependency Injection is the best way to go.  If this is too significant a refactor on your existing code, then you can also add `public static` setters for your singleton, so at least you can replace the instance.  Make sure you give those setters a name that ensures they will only be called in unit tests (e.g. `public static void SetInstanceForUnitTests(IMyService service)`)

Comment: I can't add property for change service by stub. I create instance of service in static contractor.

Answer (score 3):

Singletons are problematic from a unit testing point of view. I assume the classes using your Singleton are retrieving the instance via a static property:

```
class MyClass()
{
   public MyClass()
   {
      var myService = StaticFoo.MyServiceInstance;
   }
}
```

This is equivalent to creating a concrete class instance locally since the knowledge of "how to get to" your Singleton is part of your class implementation. What you will have to do is remove that knowledge and inject this dependency much like you would inject other dependencies on non-singletons. The most straight-forward way would be constructor injection:

```
class MyClass()
{
   public MyClass(IService myService)
   {
     //..
   }
}
```

Another needed part is either making sure all interface methods/properties in your service are defined as virtual or defining an interface or abstract base class that your service implements and which defines all the operations your class `MyClass` is using on this service. This is needed since most unit testing frameworks (including Rhino-Mocks) can only mock virtual methods / properties.

An alternative I have seen but personally don't like much, is introducing a setter in your Singleton so you can "swap out" the concrete class with your mock object needed for unit testing. This setter would only be used for unit testing and can be marked as internal so classes outside your assembly don't have access. You can then use the [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute to make a special exception for your unit testing assembly so it can see and use the setter.

The main advantage of this approach is that it requires less refactoring to arrive at a testable solution, but at a cost of "polluting" the interface of your static Singleton holder. Since in most circumstances Singletons are not needed in the first place, I would consider refactoring to constructor injection first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a public initialization method on your class that accepts an instance of the service.  You can then inject a mock object using the initialization method.